# Java Pattern/ Matcher

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

This is a **sample** text: `\1f\1e\1d\020028`. I cannot modify the input text, I am reading long string of texts from a file.

---

I want to extract the following: `\1f`, `\1e`, `\1d`, `\02`

For this, I have written the following regular expression pattern: `"\\[a-fA-F0-9]"`

I am using `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes, but my matcher is not able find the pattern using the mentioned regular expression. I have tested this regex with the text on some online regex websites and surprisingly it works there.

Where am I going wrong?

*Original* code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputText = "\1f\1e\1d\02002868BF03030000000000000000S023\1f\1e\1d\03\0d";
    inputText        = inputText.replace("\\", "\\\\");

    String regex     = "\\\\[a-fA-F0-9]{2}";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

*Output*: Nothing is printed

Comment: I'd guess that some of your backslashes are escaping things you don't intend them to.  You'd have to show us your actual code for me to be sure, though.

Comment: `\\[a-fA-F0-9]` looks for backslash followed by one letter or digit.  I think you want to look for backslash followed by two letters or digits.  I suspect you can figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Did you format input String properly? It should be '\\1f\\1e\\1d\\020028' i think.

Comment: To make helping you easier post code example of how you are using this regex.

Comment: I cannot modify the input String in the source. But yes once it is read from the file, it can be modified and extra backslashes can be added. But, I have not been successful in that.

Comment: Is this the text from your input file? Can we see how you read it? Also what do you see when you print what you red?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the file properly and replace '\' characters with '\\'. Assume that there is file called test_file in your project with this content:

```
\1f\1e\1d\02002868BF03030000000000000000S023\1f\1e\1d\03\0d
```

Here is the code to read the file and extract values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {        
    Test t = new Test();
    t.test();
}

public void test() throws IOException {        
    BufferedReader br =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test_file.txt"), "UTF-8"));
    String inputText;

    while ((inputText = br.readLine()) != null) {
        inputText = inputText.replace("\\", "\\\\");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\[a-fA-F0-9]{2}");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(inputText);

        while (match.find()) {
            System.out.println(match.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code indeed works. But, when I did something similar as you can see above, it is not working.

Comment: The problem is escaping the input String. Check an update. I used StringEscapeUtils from apache commons lang.

Comment: @bullzeye explanation `escapeJava` will return Unicode representation instead of octal one, so instead of `\1` or `\0` you will get `\u0001` or `\u0000` that is why `replace("\\u000", "\\")` is needed (to convert `\u0001` to `\1` like in your string).

Comment: @bullzeye Anyway this method fails for instance in case of `\03` because it relays on assumption that you will only have `\x` for of octal values, not `\xx` ones which could represent value greater than 15 which would need to be written using two hexadecimal character which would make escaping it return `\u00XX`.

Comment: @bullzeye Also this method will not escape characters represented by `\123` (`83` in decimal -> `'S'` character) because it is normal character used in Java language which doesn't require escaping.

Comment: You would have to search for all `\uXXXX`, and recalculate `XXXX` to octal value (not greater than `\277` since it is max Java can handle). That is actually not that hard if we use `Integer.parseInt(strValue,radix)` and `Integer.toString(intValue,radix)`.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(answer changed after OP added more details)</sub>

Your string

```
String inputText = "\1f\1e\1d\02002868BF03030000000000000000S023\1f\1e\1d\03\0d";
```

Doesn't actually contains any `\` literals because according to Java Language Specification in section [3.10.6. Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) `\xxx` will be interpreted as character indexed in Unicode Table with [octal (base/radix 8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) value represented by `xxx` part.

Example `\123` = **1***8<sup>2</sup> + **2***8<sup>1</sup> + **3***8<sup>0</sup> = 1*64 + 2*8 + 3*1 = 64+16+3 = **83** which represents [character `S`](http://unicode-table.com/en/0053/)

If string you presented in your question is written exactly the same in your text file then you should write it as

```
String inputText = "\\1f\\1e\\1d\\02002868BF03030000000000000000S023\\1f\\1e\\1d\\03\\0d";
```

(with escaped `\` which now will represent literal).

---

(older version of my answer)

It is hard to tell what exactly you did wrong without seeing your code. You should be able to find at least `\1`, `\1`, `\1`, `\0` since your regex can match one `\` and one hexadecimal character placed after it.

Anyway this is how you can find results you mentioned in question:

```
String text = "\\1f\\1e\\1d\\020028";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\[a-fA-F0-9]{2}");
//                                          ^^^--we want to find two hexadecimal 
//                                               characters after \
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
\1f
\1e
\1d
\02
```

Comment: The code you mentioned works. But, when I did something similar as you can see above, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a . at the end, like:

```
\\[a-fA-F0-9].
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the input string, you could try something like:

```
static public void main(String[] argv) {

            String s = "\1f\1e\1d\020028";
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[\\x00-\\x1f][0-9A-Fa-f]");
            Matcher match = regex.matcher(s);
            while (match.find()) {
                    char[] c = match.group().toCharArray();
                    System.out.println(String.format("\\%d%s",c[0]+0, c[1])) ;
            }
    }
```

Yes, it's not perfect, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you! This solution works partially. For the input string as I mentioned in my modified answer, following is the output: '\1f
\1e
\1d
\160
\1f
\1e
\1d
\0d'