# In Java how to replace Number and Decimal with string

Tags: java, regex

I am having the below string.

```
Functions.substring(Functions.test(1,Functions.test("TestString1")),0.9,0,"TestString2",true)
```

In the above string, I want to replace Numbers(0 and 1 as in the above example) as Integer. And Float Values(`Ex: 0.9`) as Decimal and  String(`EX: "TestString1" and "TestString2"`) as String.

Result: `Functions.substring(Functions.test(Integer,Functions.test(String)),Decimal,Integer,String,true)`

I tried with replace function using below regex but it is not working.

```
decimal: ^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$
number : ^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\d+)?$
String : ".*?"
```

Below is the java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("Functions.substring(Functions.test(1,Functions.test(\"TestString1\")),0.9,0,\"TestString2\",true)".replaceAll("^-?(0|[1-9]\\d*)(\\d+)?$", "Intger"));
    }
```

Comment: *but it is not working* is no error description. What is what you get?

Comment: First problem is that you can't use "^" and "$" because they mean beginning a end of a line which is the entire string in this case, but in your sample text you have text before and after the numbers you want to replace.

Comment: In this example, what is the expected output?

Comment: It appears that your intention is to identify and then replace certain values within a String using regular expressions in Java. Are other approaches (languages, tools) also possible for you? If so, then you should restate the problem using less specific implementation details. A simpler example of your difficulty will be clearer for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

For the Integer part you have to do something like this:

```
System.out.println("Functions.substring(Functions.test(1,Functions.test(\"TestString1\")),0.9,99,\"TestString2\",true)".replaceAll("(?<=\\(|,)\\d+(?=\\)|,|$)", "Intger"));
```

For Decimal and String you have to adapt the code.

Probably you will be better served with Pattern and Matcher. An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767866/java-pattern-matcher).